# XML - XPath to return element that brother element contains certain text

Tags: html, xml, firefox, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to find the correct xpath expression to select the parent of an element where contains a certain text.

In the example below, I would like to select the "span" element with text matching "4" or any other number and the parent matches with the text "Rooms":

**My XPath example** - matches every "span" inside the "div" element

`//div/span[../span[contains(text(), 'Rooms')]]`

**Source Code**

```
<div>
    <span>4</span>
    <span>Rooms</span>
    <span>and 2 suites</span>
</div>
```

What I want is to select the "span" element that contains the number four as text, but as the html could change and maybe have just two or one "span" element(s) as the example below:

```
<div>
    <span>2 Rooms</span>
</div>
```

**or**

```
<div>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>Rooms</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//div/span[contains(text(), 'Rooms')]/preceding-sibling::span[1] | div[count(span)=1 and contains(span/text(), 'Rooms')]/span
```

It merges the nodeset of the preceding-siblings of `span`s which contain the text "Rooms" with the first `span` element if it's the only one (count=1).

Result is:

```
<span>4</span>
<span>2 Rooms</span>
<span>3</span>
```

Comment: As I said in the above answer, I would like to select the span element before the span matching the "Rooms" value.

Comment: As you can see in the result, my expression does achieve that. It selects the `<span>` with the number that precedes the `<span>` with "Rooms". But if there's only one `<span>` element, it checks if it contains "Rooms", and if so, it selects that.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just tested with the wrong parameters, it was my mistake, worked as a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This XPath

```
//span[contains(.," Rooms") or following-sibling::*[1][self::span]="Rooms"]
```

will select the `span` whose string value contains " Rooms" or whose immediately following `span` sibling has a string value equal to "Rooms".

Comment: I would like to select the `span` element that contains the number value of "Rooms" (the element before the `span` matching the "Rooms" value)

Comment: I fixed a mistake, sorry.  I think you'll find it works well and is fairly short.  If there are other variations you need to account for, it can be extended easily.